# Line containing more than one keyword

Tags: java

When I have the following textfile which contains

```
GET GET document

GET A B C 
B------>C
```

Basically, I want to check if the textfile contains/has "GET" and do further actions. If it contains more than one "GET" so would need to get both of them and do further same actions. How can I know if I have to "GET" words in a textfile?

```
public Scanner getCircuitScanner(String circuitName) throws IOException
    {
        Scanner data = new Scanner(new File(circuitName));
        while(data.hasNextLine())
        {
            String line = data.nextLine();
            if(line.contains("GET"))
        }
    }
```

Comment: Just write a regex, what's wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to find all the lines that contain "GET"?  ...or just check the file in general?

Comment: to find all of the keywords "GET" @Bubletan

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you do with them, but to simply get the start positions of the "GET" keywords, you can do this:

```
int index = line.indexOf("GET");
while (index != -1) {
    // Do something with "GET" at index here
    index = line.indexOf("GET", index + 3);
}
```